# Contact form sending blank emails sometimes, although working perfectly

Tags: javascript, php

there is a form I created, but many times emails show up with nothing in the body. The input fields are coming blank. I’ve tried finding the cause, but I haven’t been able to rectify the problem. Does anyone know what might be causing this? and how to resolve this.
I am using this contact form for downloading pdf.

Here is the code:

````
<div class="modal fade" id="over">
    <p id="messageDownload" style="display:none;">Thank you for download, we will contact you shortly!</p>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="panel panel-default contact bg-edit bg-blue" style="margin-bottom:0;max-width:500px;">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <form id="loginForm" novalidate="novalidate">           
            <div class="row" style="max-width:500px;">
                <p class="text-uppercase my-font-style" align="center">Fill Your Contact Details</p>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="name1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name1" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="email1" type="email" class="form-control" name="email1" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <input id="mobile1" placeholder="Phone" name="mobile1" type="text" class="form-control input-inverse iti-phone" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <input type="hidden" name="site_name" value="<?php echo $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; ?>" />
                <button onclick="insert()" type="button" class="btn btn-white" name="sub">Download</button>      
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>    

<!--End Download Modal-->

<!--start donwload link-->
<div>
    <a id="link" href="abc.pdf" class="" download hidden></a>
    <button type="button" data-bname="abc.pdf" onclick="document.getElementById('link').href=this.getAttribute('data-bname');  Dat()" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">&nbsp;Download</button>
</div>
<!--End Download link-->

<!-- start download.js -->
<style>
function insert() {
    var name1 = $("#name1").val();
    var namev = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    var email1 = $("#email1").val();
    var emailv = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var mobile1 = $("#mobile1").val();
    var mobilev = (/^[0-9]+$/);

    if (name1 === null || name1 === "" || namev.test(name1) === false) {
    alert("Please enter your name.");
    return false;
    } else if (email1 === null || email1 === "" || emailv.test(email1) === false) {
    alert("Please enter email.");
    return false;
    } else if (mobile1 === null || mobile1 === "" || mobilev.test(mobile1) === false) {
    alert("Please enter your mobile.");
    return false;
    } else {
    var formdata = $("#loginForm").serialize() + '&c_code1=' + document.getElementsByClassName('selected-flag')[0].title;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "download_send.php",
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data) {
        $("#messageDownload").css('display', 'block');
        $('#loginForm').html($("#messageDownload"));
        $("#messageDownload.p").addClass("alert-default");
        },
    });
    }
    document.getElementById('link').click()
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#over').modal('hide');
    }, 10000);
}
</style>
<!-- end download.js -->

<!-- start download_send.php -->

<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dubai");
$ddate = date(' d-m-Y H:i:s');

function get_client_ipsp() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

extract($_POST);
$site_name = str_replace("http://", "", $site_name);
$site_name = str_replace(".php", "", $site_name);
$msg = "Name:- " . $name1 . "\r\n" . "Email:- " . $email1 . "\r\n" . "Phone:- (" . $c_code1 . ")" . $mobile1 . "\r\n" . "IP Addr:- " . get_client_ipsp();
$headers = "From: $name1 <enquiry@abc.com>" . "\r\n" . "CC: enquiry@abc.com" . "\r\n" . "BCC: leads@abc.com";

mail("sales@abc.com", $ddate . ' Enquiry from ' . $site_name . '(Download Form)', $msg, $headers);
echo'your message has been sent';
?>

<!-- end download_send.php --> ```
````

Comment: If you retrieve field values correctly, at the beginning try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData instead of `.serialize` from jQuery docs `The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation` and this is not the same. What means "sometimes" - can you identify when?

Comment: When someone sends the query it's delivered perfectly but along with another blank query. Sometimes I have been received only a blank query.

Comment: So query is send twice and second is blank or there are blank fields inside single query?

Comment: Sometimes Both conditions happened. But when I send a query to check, it received perfectly. That's why I am unable to rectify the problem.